# use backpack permission manager in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using backpack for laravel V4, Laravel 6, I defined roles and permissions and assigned `file-manager` permission and `manager` role to a user. When I try to use it in route middleware I get Forbidden Error 403, what I tried:
in `routes/backpack/custom.php`

```
'middleware' => ['web', config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin'), 'can:file-manager']
```

when I use as instructed in `spatie/laravel-permission` [documentation](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:manager']], function () {
    //
});
```

I receive `Target class [role] does not exist` error.

I searched different places but no luck, please advise the right way to use permission manager in routes.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.

You must add the `RoleMiddleware` to your config, in `app/Http/Kernel.php` :

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
   // [...]
   'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
];
```

My answer is a bit late, but I hope it will help others :)